# FullPage.js - different paddings in mobile and desktop versions

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and I want set different paddings in mobile and desktop versions.

I can set padding-top and padding bottom in settings but I don't know how set different values for different window width.

Comment: add some code and highlight the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Not an option fullPage.js provides.

I would encourage you to make use of a container within your section or slides and work with your own paddings:

```
<div class="section">
   <div class="container">
   </div>
</div>
```

Then:

```
.container{
    padding-top: 40px
}
```